# How to cache data via Guava Cache using available memory as parameter?

Tags: java, guava

It is possible remove data from cache, when available runtime memory near with overflow? The cache implementetion is below:

```
Cache<String, Cache<String, List<String>>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumWeight((int) ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024) * 0.9))
            .weigher((Weigher<String, Cache<String, List<String>>>) (key, val) -> runtimeMemory())
            .build();

public static int runtimeMemory() {
        long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024;
        long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024;
        return (int) (totalMemory - freeMemory);
    }
```

It is work or no ? Or weigher summarizes runtimeMemory() for each value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no good way for Guava's Cache -- or any on-heap cache implementation, honestly -- to do what you ask.  Soft references may appear to work, but are much more likely to cause awful behavior -- e.g. your JVM may perform continuous, constant full garbage collections.

The best way to address this issue is really and truly to experiment and find a `maximumSize` parameter that works for you.  Your implementation will not work, either, as it doesn't attempt to weigh one particular entry.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to avoid running out of memory JVM-wide, then the garbage collector is the right guy for the job. I suggest you use [soft-values](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#softValues--), like so:

```
Cache<String, Cache<String, List<String>>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .softValues()
        .build();
```

This sets up a cache which wraps any value it stores in a [SoftReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html). Softly-referenced objects will be garbage-collected in a globally least-recently-used manner in response to memory demand and entry invalidated in the cache.